# Topological order and volume-law entanglement

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, topological-order, topological-phase

Topological order is a property traditionally most associated with ground states of gapped Hamiltonians. However, using the notion that topological order is fundamentally about a form of "long-range entanglement", it is possible to give a definition of topological order which applies to individual states. For example, following Eq. 4 of Ref. 1, one definition would be:

> **Definition (topological order):** A state $|\psi\rangle$ has topological order if there does not exist a finite-depth local unitary quantum circuit $U$ such that $|\psi\rangle = U|0\rangle$, where $|0\rangle$ is a trivial product state.

(Some argue that one should generalize this slightly to include stochastic local transformations --- I will ignore these subtleties in this question.)

This generalization to individual states allows one to capture the notion that, for example, energy eigenstates in the bulk of the spectrum of many-body localized (MBL) Hamiltonians can be topologically ordered.

One commonality between these two examples is that ground states of gapped Hamiltonians and MBL eigenstates both have area-law entanglement. In both cases one can link this to the presence of a gap: via the standard folklore of "gap implies area-law" in the first case, and via the presence of a gap to *local* excitations in the second.

I must admit though that I find the fact that topological order is most typically associated with *area-law* entanglement slightly curious. Namely, topologically ordered states are a) non-trivially entangled in the sense that their entanglement is "long-range", but b) only weakly entangled in the sense that the entanglement is only area-law. This is not a contradiction of course, but it does seem like there is some tension in the idea that topologically ordered states are "highly entangled".

This leads to my **question**: is it possible to realize some notion of topological order in more highly entangled states, such as those with volume-law entanglement? Or is there some fundamental reason to think that this is impossible?

Some notes to the question:

- I am being deliberately vague about precisely how these states should be topologically ordered. Indeed, the definition I gave above of topological order is probably inappropriate in this case, since *all* volume-law states would be counted as topologically ordered because of linear upper bounds on the rate of entanglement generation via e.g. Lieb-Robinson bounds.
- To give a flavour of what I am looking for, recently I have read some papers exploring (SPT) topological order in *gapless* 1+1D systems [2], which I imagine have logarithmic rather than area-law entanglement. Despite this lack of an area-law, these systems display some familiar hallmarks of topological order, such as protected edge modes and string order parameters. I am wondering whether similar phenomenology could also be found in volume-law entangled states.
- Can this be related to the stability of topological order at finite temperature?
- There are some similarities between topologically ordered states and the volume-law eigenstates of chaotic Hamiltonians, in that both form quantum error-correcting codes [3,4]. In the latter case though these are more like random codes, and perhaps do not deserve to be called "topological", even though they do encode information in long-range patterns of entanglement.

#### References

[1] X. Chen, Z-C. Gu, X. G. Wen, *"Local unitary transformation, long-range quantum entanglement, wave function renormalization, and topological order"*, [PRB **82**, 155138 (2010)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.155138).

[2] R. Thorngren, A. Vishwanath, R. Verresen, *"Intrinsically Gapless Topological Phases"*, [arXiv:2008.06638 (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.06638).

[3] S. B. Bravyi, A. Kitaev *"Quantum codes on a lattice with boundary"*, [arXiv:quant-ph/9811052 (1998)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9811052).

[4] F. G. S. L. Brandão, E. Crosson, M. Burak Şahinoğlu, J. Bowen, *"Quantum Error Correcting Codes in Eigenstates of Translation-Invariant Spin Chains"*, [PRL **123**, 110502 (2019)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.110502).

Comment: *Some* notion of "topological": sure - there is no unique definition (or maybe no definition at all) what "topological" means. To me, the most meaningful Hamiltonian-free definition of "topological" would be: "A state which supports local excitations (defined as local deformations of the state, no H needed) which have non-trivial statistics." No idea if your states fit in there. Then again, with your "circuit" definition, basically any state is "topological". But those two are very different definitions.

Comment: And if you want a stupid example, just tensor a topological state with a random state: Volume law and topological order by any definition. Voila!  ---  Long story short: The way you ask now virtually any answer is possible. You could ask about different definitions of topological order, or the possibility to have a volume law w.r.t. a specific definition.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I agree that possible answers will strongly depend on the definition of "topological". I'm not particularly wedded to the circuit definition - I just want to focus on states rather than Hamiltonians. Let us use the definition of "topological" in terms of non-trivial statistics you gave in your comment. Is area-law entanglement a necessary ingredient to be "topological" in this sense?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. I'm quite sue the stupid example I gave works with basically any definition. It is just that the entanglement which has area-law scaling and the one which gives rise to the topological properties are completely different entanglements, and this might not be what you are after. (Though again - ruling out such "cheating" examples might be rather subtle.)

Comment: Also, note that you *can* get volume-law in ground states - they are just not gapped.

Comment: I think fundamentally what I am trying to understand is the "tension" (don't know if you agree) between common examples of topologically ordered states being a) non-trivially entangled in the sense of having "long-range entanglement", but b) being only weakly entangled in the sense of having an area-law. Is there a reason that states supporting excitations with non-trivial statistics cannot be too entangled?

Comment: One guess in the context of Hamiltonians would be something like "the topological effects are protected by a gap, and, separately, it happens that a gap tends to imply an area-law". In that case the area-law would be a byproduct of the gap, rather than a causal ingredient for the topological order.

Comment: Ideally I would like to rule out "cheating" examples like the one you mentioned, though I agree that making this precise could be subtle. This is not really my field, so I'm afraid I don't have a good idea of how to do this properly, sorry!

Comment: All ground states in reasonable spin systems obey an area law, even critical ones. The "worst" thing which happens in systems appearing in physics is for *fermionic* systems, which can have a log(Area) (=log(Volume)) divergence, which is much closer to "area law" than to "volume law".

Comment: I agree, but my question is not just about ground states. Admittedly I do not know many examples of topologically ordered states that are not ground states. The main example I can think of are MBL eigenstates, but in some sense these look "locally" like gapped ground states, so perhaps this is not really a new example. But let us suppose there were some example of a state which is not a ground state, but which nonetheless is "topological" under your definition. Would we still expect it to be area-law *in order to be topological*, despite the fact that it is no longer a ground state?

Comment: I'm not even sure whether states which are topological under my definition can be non-groundstates, or whether one can always find a (quasi-)local Hamiltonian whose g.s. they are. And yet again: I *gave* you an example of such a state. If you think it is stupid (which it is) and you want to rule it out, you have to be more precise in what you want. Otherwise, this is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: I think the problem is that this is outside of my field, so I do not know how to make this precise enough to rule out the example you gave. The fact that you called it stupid as you introduced it suggests you have some idea of what I *don't* want, but I suppose I was asking you to do more interpretive work than is reasonable on a site like PSE with many questions! At any rate, thank you for the time you have spent on this so far.

Comment: Let me make one final attempt at turning this into a question appropriate for PSE. I recently saw https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.09376 , which derives several of the axioms of the algebraic theory of anyons solely from the assumption of an area-law. This works for any state satisfying the area-law assumption, so it does not matter if it is a ground state or not. To me this suggests that an area-law is an important causal ingredient for “topological order”, taken to mean the emergence of non-trivial statistics.

Comment: My question is whether there is some basic intuition for why we would expect an area-law to imply all these properties? On p3 the authors say that the key concept is the “information convex set”, which roughly is a set of density matrices which are locally indistinguishable from some reference state. But here I am confused, because one could also get local indistinguishability from Haar-random states, but they are volume-law entangled. So an area-law seems important for local indistinguishability which is topological in the sense of anyons, and I am trying to understand why this is so.

Comment: One intuition why Haar-random states are not good is that they are "too entangled" - if every local reduced density matrix is maximally mixed, there is not even a notion of "local excitations" (i.e. stuff created by local operations). See e.g. also https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4331